# Can I keep my database on my local network but deploy my rails app on a hosting service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, deployment

I have a rails application that is currently hosted on Heroku.  It is used on our local network only, and my boss does not want a 3rd party hosting our data.  I convinced IT to set me up a virtual windows server to deploy my app on.  However, it has been very difficult to set up for production.

Is there anyway that I can use a hosting service for my application, but have the database reside on our local network?

Or is there an easier way to deploy a rails app on a windows server?  I have been looking into using the Linux Subsystem for Windows.

Comment: This phenomenon is called "Hybrid Cloud Computing", aka "Edge computing".

Answer (score 1):

If your app is used on your local network only, why not ditch Heroku and host your Rails app locally as well? What benefit is a scalable cloud hosting provider giving you? Especially since it seems your boss has security concerns about remote hosting of a database. Bringing the entire thing in house may be the best solution.

Comment: The problem is that I am having trouble deploying on the Windows Server VM that IT has supplied me with.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is yes you can, but why would you. It's simpler to run your application locally than connecting your remote app to a local database.

Your best bet is to use a Linux virtual machine instead of Windows, usually there is to much hassle to get rails application to work on windows, especially compiling native gems.

I suggest that you get a CentOS VM, and install Nginx with passenger gem using rbenv or rvm.

Digital Ocean has a nice guide that explains this process in details:
[How To Deploy Rails Apps Using Passenger With Nginx on CentOS 6.5](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-rails-apps-using-passenger-with-nginx-on-centos-6-5)

Comment: I'll ask the sys admin if he can set me up a Linux server but our ecosystem is mostly Microsoft based so I'm not sure if that's an option.  If it isn't, what about installing a CentOS VM on my Windows Server VM?  Or is that ridiculous?

Comment: If it works it is not ridiculous. You can also use bitnami packages to install ruby on windows: https://bitnami.com/stack/ruby/installer